# How can I dual-wield two daggers?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, two-weapon-fighting

I'm currently playing as a Lizardfolk Warlock (Dungeons & Dragons 5E) and my character started with two daggers. Is there anyway to simultaneously attack with them while in combat?
If I were to dual-wield them, how should I proceed?

Comment: Can you please specify the game and edition? (i.e. dnd 5e)

Comment: I forgot to do it, thanks. Already fixed the original post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wielding two weapons without "Two-Weapon Fighting" or "Dual Wielder"?](/questions/69521) or [Two-Weapon Fighting & Bonus Action in 5e](/questions/49685)

Comment: What do you mean by 'simultaneously attack' with them?

Comment: @Justin Attack with both daggers in the same turn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the two weapon fighting rule.

In the [basic combat rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting), it states:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
>   that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack
>   with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
>   hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.
>
> If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee attack with it.

Since you have one dagger in each hand, you can attack (melee or ranged) with each dagger on your turn.